# Django - History breadcrumb "dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 9; 2 is required"

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a breadcrumb based on user history, i.e it will show in a bread crumb the last x amount of pages visited.

i found a blog which has already done what i wanted (http://seancode.blogspot.co.uk/2008/10/breadcrumb-history-in-django.html)

so used that, i thought id add it to context processors and add it to my settings to save putting it in every view.

however im getting the error

```
        Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://it.internal.com/service/

Django Version: 1.9.6
Python Version: 2.7.5
Installed Applications:
('home.apps.HomeConfig',
 'oncall.apps.OncallConfig',
 'networks.apps.NetworksConfig',
 'maintenance.apps.MaintenanceConfig',
 'service.apps.ServiceConfig',
 'management.apps.ManagementConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'twitter_bootstrap',
 'bootstrap_pagination')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware')



Traceback:

File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/var/www/infternal/service/views.py" in index
  20.     return render(request, 'service/index.html', {

File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  67.             template_name, context, request=request, using=using)

File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  97.         return template.render(context, request)

File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  95.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  204.                 with context.bind_template(self):

File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/contextlib.py" in __enter__
  17.             return self.gen.next()

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/templates/panel.py" in _request_context_bind_template
  81.             updates.update(context)

Exception Type: ValueError at /service/
Exception Value: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 9; 2 is required
```

but i have no idea what this means, or how to fix it

code

```
# the breadcrumb history is a list of the last pages the user has visited
# the newest page is at the end of the list
# the length of the list is limited; currently it is at four pages
def breadcrumb_history(request):
    history = request.session.get('breadcrumb_history', [])

    # if the last item in the history is the current page, we don't want to add this page to the history
    # if it's not the last item in the history, we do add it
    if len(history) == 0 or history[len(history)-1] != request.path:
        history.append(request.path)

    # if there are more than four items in the history, pop the first one
    if len(history) > 4:
        history.pop(0)

    # save the history to the session
    request.session['breadcrumb_history'] = history

    # return the current breadcrumb
    return history
```

settings.py

```
       TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'debug' : DEBUG,
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                "django.core.context_processors.request",
                "django.core.context_processors.media",
                "django.core.context_processors.static",
                "infternal.context_processors.breadcrumb_history",
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

template:

```
<div id="page-content" class="">
        {% if breadcrumb_history %}
        <p class="breadcrumb">
        {% for page in breadcrumb_history %}
        <a href="{{ page }}">{{ page }}</a>
        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Show the full traceback. What is the line that triggers this error?

Comment: Also note that you can get the last element in the list by doing `history[-1]`.

Comment: ive added the full traceback. so in any tempalte i can do history[-1] and get the last page? does that work up to 4 pages?

Comment: No, I just meant you can do `history[-1]` rather than `history[len(history)-1]`.

Comment: And the traceback shows that the error is coming in django-debug-toolbar, but also that the code you have shown is not the actual view. Please show that view.

Comment: as soon as i uncomment "infternal.context_processors.breadcrumb_history" in the settings all pages show that error

Comment: Right, now I understand: this is a context processor. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Context processors always need to return a dictionary, but you're returning a list. Instead you should do:

```
return {'history': history}
```